# "Screen is not a member of My.MyComputer"

Tags: ajax, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am very interested in using AJAX (via/with Visual Studio 2012) to make my webpage more dynamic. However I am terribly confused by this error I am getting..

> 'Screen' is not a member of "My.MyComputer"

All I want to do is get the screen size.
I've looked all over Google and found almost every time that the only way to do this is:

```
My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height
My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width
```

Or

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Screen.PriamryScreen.Bounds.Height
```

I get the error every time.. It's a little different for the second method; it says:

> 'Screen' hasn't been declared.

Comment: The `Screen` object is found in the namespace, `System.Windows.Forms` This is not going to be in a Web Forms project by default. Also, this is probably the wrong way to accomplish whatever you are doing. The `Screen` object will refer to the server side -- and not the client side. It would be better to investigate how to grab this data via client-side.

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: No, not JQuery. I am attempting to call a Sub via an event on the web Form. All in VB; no javascript

Comment: Web pages don't have screens, they have at most a browser window.  Several thousand miles away from where your code runs, you can't see it.  A pretty fundamental difference between web apps and Winforms apps, you can't ignore that *two* computers are involved.  Well, a lot more than two when you have more than one guy visiting your page.  They all have different screen sizes.

Answer (score 3):

In **JavaScript** it is lowercase `screen`:

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

**DEMO:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/fXS8k/)

In `.net` as [@GeorgeJohnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225239/george-johnston) pointed out you need:

> The Screen object is found in the namespace, System.Windows.Forms This is not going to be in a Web Forms project by default.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering about doing this Javascript action via server side script though

Comment: always welcome. Since your question is about javascript, will you add the JavaScript tag to your question

Comment: Interesting, i'd recommend getting the clients window size on the client side as opposed to the server side.  Since the server side would likely return it's own resolution.  But this is just my opinion, please do what you have to do.  Thanks!

Comment: You are very right; I know the client method is the easiest and probably most orthodox way to achieve this.. But I'd really like to stay away from client side script especially in terms of structure